# Wrong report summary calculation

Tags: reporting

We have a report to calculate the commission of sales but seems like the summary isn't working here I attach a screencap  link to the values.

[image: Screencap]

This is how Comission_client is calculated :
[image: ComissionClient Formula]

The sum should be 443,49 but instead we're getting this result, could someone point out why? Thanks.

Comment: Is commission_client a currency field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is most probably that the AVG values are being calculated separately for each level. That will result in different averages on detail level compared to grand summary level. The different averages will consequently result in different formula results on different level, and thus different outcomes.

The behaviour that you are looking for is a calculation of the summary field on detail level, then a summation of the summary field on higher level(s). This is not possible with summary fields.

The only solution I see is to either hide the grand-summary level or to do the factor calculation offline some way (through formulas or code).